# Haskell : continuing recursion for extra step

Tags: haskell

If I have a recursive function that does comparisons on every element on a list; what is the best way to have it do an extra step at then end as if the list had an extra 0 on the end, without actually appending 0 to the list in the first place.

```
rect xs = maximum $ go 0 [] (xs ++ [0]) where
  go i s                     []     = []
  go i ((_, tH):r@((t,_):_)) (h:hs) | h < tH = tH * (i - t - 1) : go i r (h:hs)
  go i s                     (h:hs) = go (i + 1) ((i,h):s)  hs
```

I am think that there must be a better way than doing the `xs ++ [0]` but I can't come up with it.

Note: The function is to find the largest rectangle in a histogram

Comment: You could define a second helper function `go'` that mimics `go`, so that you can call `go i s [] = go' i s [0]`, but I think that would get more complicated than what you have now. What you have now looks fine.

Comment: @chepner having a part in a function that adds a whole extra walk through of the list seems painful (doubling the number of passes just for one extra step)

Comment: It's not an extra walk; `++` is lazy, so each time you try to get an element from the list, `h:hs` just gets matched against `x : xs ++ [0]` instead of `x:xs`. `++` is only bad if you try to build up a list by appending to it one item at a time; here, you are only appending one single item.

Comment: @chepner I actually totally forgot about the lazy evaluation... thanks

Comment: @chepner It is an extra walk. Each time you try to get an element from the list, `h:hs` gets matched against `xs ++ [0]`; to evaluate `xs ++ [0]`, the `y:ys` pattern in the implementation of `++` gets matched against `xs`. This is one extra match compared to not having called `++` -- in other words, over the course of touching the whole list, you have done one extra walk.

Comment: Oh, right. I was thinking of the quadratic blow-up you get, for example, when you try to reverse a string with `reverse (x:xs) == xs ++ [0]`.

Answer (score 3):

Modify your base case and unroll the loop one step. It leads to a bit of code duplication, but it doesn't look too terrible.

```
rect' xs = maximum $ go 0 [] xs where
  go i ((_, tH):r@((t,_):_)) []     | 0 < tH = tH * (i - t - 1) : go i r []
  go i s                     []     = []
  go i ((_, tH):r@((t,_):_)) (h:hs) | h < tH = tH * (i - t - 1) : go i r (h:hs)
  go i s                     (h:hs) = go (i + 1) ((i,h):s)  hs
```

Comment: Is this really equivalent? The original code, on `[0]` could recurse as `[0]` or `[]`, depending on `0<tH`. Here we always recurse as `[]`, which however is handled as `[0]`. It's not completely obvious to me.

Comment: @chi I will answer in two ways: with an argument that it's correct, and with evidence. 1. It is correct: this code, when encountering `[]` (which really represents `[0]`) also dispatches on `0<tH`. In one case it recurses like the original; in the other it doesn't, but if you look carefully at the original code you'll see that the "recursive" step it would do in that case always returns `[]`, so recursion isn't actually needed. 2. QuickCheck does not find any examples where these two functions differ, even if you take the call to `maximum` out of both to make it easier to find counterexamples.

Comment: the code duplication was something I was hoping to avoid. I guess my implementation of the the algorithm is the problem. Do you have any suggestions of what I should i have done in the first place to avoid this problem?

Comment: @matthias Could you describe what you're trying to compute a bit more? I don't really understand your description or your code -- I arrived at this answer through purely mechanical transformations of your code, without being guided by intuition or insight.

Comment: Its a solution to finding the biggest rectangle in a histogram. (this problem https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/largest-rectangle-under-histogram/).  The algorithm is described there. It would be too much to write as a comment but basically  "We traverse all bars from left to right, maintain a stack of bars. Every bar is pushed to stack once. A bar is popped from stack when a bar of smaller height is seen. When a bar is popped, we calculate the area with the popped bar as smallest bar".